# Provisioning Profile/Certificate for custom Entitlements.plist in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, certificate

I'm developing an app in Xamarin.iOS (`Xamarin Studio 6.3 (build 863)` and `xCode 8.3 (8E162)` on `macOS Sierra 10.12`) for iPhone. With my AppleID (developer Account) I created certificates and provisioning profiles according to Xamarin's documentation and it worked so far.

[image: certificates]
[image: provisioning profiles]
[image: App IDs]
The provisioning profiles contain all the device's UDIDs and I could deliver the App via HockeyApp and test it on the devices.

Now I've included a custom `Entitlements.plist` because I need a keychain access group. The file only contains a single entry `Keychain Access Group` which has a single String value `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)my.app.id`

[image: iOS Bundle signing with custom Entitlements.plist]
Now I get an error when I try to install the App on the same devices as before, using the same certificates and provisioning profiles as before.

`Unable to download application, <app-name> could not be installed at this time`

So I assume I somehow need to sign the custom `Entitlements.plist` but I have actually no idea left where to look for a corresponding setting in XamarinStudio.